# pyspider : No module named 'wsgidav'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspider, wsgidav

I am using python 3.5.2 on windows 10,I installed pyspider,and run `pyspider all`,there are some errors,as follow:
[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

wsgidav doesn't support python3. Just ignore it, pyspider can still run without the feature.

UPDATE: Both pyspider and wsgidav working with python3 now. Thanks for the work of @mar10

Comment: Note that starting with version 2, wsgidav *does* support Python 3.